# Поиск через парсинг средствами JSOUP

Tags: java, android, json, jsoup

Можно ли реализовать поиск в приложении, но c сайта? Запрос пишешь в приложении, а ищет через поиск на сайте.

Comment: Не совсем. Там, я так понял, нужно просто распарсить событие, ответ. А мне надо задать вопрос у себя в приложение и распарсить ответ с сайта. Парсить я умею, как реализовать запрос

Comment: Суть такая же: необходимо определить url-запроса и параметры, которые необходимо передать, для формы поиска. На основе этих данных собрать url запроса и выполнить его с помощью `Jsoup`.

Comment: вам нужно сделать точно такой же запрос, как и на сайте для поиска. Посмотрите, как поиск реализован на сайте, и сделайте так же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите как на сайте реализован поиск. К примеру, если есть явный урл для поиска, типа www.address.com/search?=search_me, то вместо search_me передавайте нужный вам текст, после чего парсите то, что получилось.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Именно так и сделал

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександров Незачто)